# Using " { Dialog,Transition } from '@headlessui/react' " to create side bar

Tags: reactjs, next.js, headless-ui

using transition I want to create side bar for my website everything is working fine except when side bar is closed scroll bar appears before sidebar closing animation has completed making it a bad UI .

```
<Transition.Root appear show={isShelfOpen} as={Fragment} enter="ease-out duration-1000" enterFrom="opacity-100" enterTo="opacity-100" leave="ease-in duration-1000" leaveFrom="opacity-100" leaveTo="opacity-100" className="fixed bg-gray-950/40 top-0 left-0 bottom-0 h-full w-screen">
  <Dialog as="div" className="fixed inset-0 overflow-y-auto bg-gray-950/40 top-0 left-0 bottom-0 h-full w-screen" onClose={handleClose}>
    <Transition.Child as={Fragment} enter="ease-in-out duration-1000" enterFrom="opacity-100" enterTo="opacity-100" leave="ease-in-out duration-1000" leaveFrom="opacity-100" leaveTo="opacity-100">
      <Dialog.Overlay className="fixed top-0 left-0 h-full w-2/3" />
    </Transition.Child>

    <Transition.Child as={Fragment} enter="ease-out duration-1000" enterFrom="translate-x-full" enterTo="translate-x-0" leave="ease-in duration-1000" leaveFrom="translate-x-0" leaveTo="translate-x-full">
      <div className="w-full items-center p-4 bg-gray-200 dark:bg-gray-700 flex flex-col md:w-1/3 sm:w-1/2 fixed top-0 right-0 ml-auto h-full">
        <button onClick={handleClose} className="p-2 ml-auto text-black border border-black dark:text-white dark:border-white rounded hover:text-red-600 dark:hover:text-red-400 hover:border-red-600 dark:hover:border-red-400 outline-none-s">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" strokeWidth="1.5" stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true" className="w-6 h-6">
            <path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12"></path>
          </svg>
        </button>
        <h1 className="text-4xl self-start font-bold text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-300">Shelved Books</h1>
        <div className="flex flex-col items-center w-full overflow-y-auto px-3 overflow-x-hidden">
          {shelfBook.length > 0 ? shelfBook.map((book) => <ShelfBook key={book.id} book={book} removeFromShelf={() => removeFromShelf(book.id)} />) : (
            <div className="h-full mt-32 border">
              <MessageContainer messageText="No Books To Show" fontSize="text-5xl" fontWeight="font-bold">
                <button onClick={() => { handleClose(); if (pathname !== '/') { router.push('/'); } }} className="mt-4 px-4 py-2 mx-auto my-2 font-bold text-white bg-blue-500 dark:bg-sky-800 dark:hover:bg-sky-700 rounded hover:bg-blue-700">
                  Go Back to Library
                </button>
              </MessageContainer>
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </Transition.Child>
  </Dialog>
</Transition.Root>
```

I tried adding setTimeout it delays the whole animation and not just scrollbar appearing . I played with every dialog and transition . do not know what I missed .
[this is side bar with its scrollbar and no scrollbar for page in background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiHrd.png)
[here side bar is still closing and scroll bar for page in back has appeared](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtrAj.png)